# Having trouble turning radio buttons into responsive star ratings. I am able to get non-resposive stars or responsive radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, rating

I've tried different variations of the code, adding the star image as a png, adding it as a Unicode image but I'm still getting either none responsive stars or only responsive radio buttons. I'm really not sure what I'm missing. It looks like it should work but clearly something is missing when it comes to the 'star' image in the code. I'm guessing with the CSS code?

**<!HTML>**

```
<div class="col-4">
        <img src="images/g13.jpg">
        <h4>Green X-Mas</h4>
        <p>$35.00</p>


        <div class="rate">
     <input type="radio" id="star5.3" name="rate.3" value="5" />
     <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star4.3" name="rate.3" value="4" />
     <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star3.3" name="rate.3" value="3" />
     <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star2.3" name="rate.3" value="2" />
     <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
     <input type="radio" id="star1.3" name="rate.3" value="1" />
     <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

**/*CSS star rating*/**

```
'''.rate {
float: left;
height: 46px;
padding: 0 10px;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > input {
position:absolute;
top:-9999px;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label {
float:right;
width:1em;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
cursor:pointer;
font-size:30px;
color:#ccc;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
content: '★ ';
}

.rate > input:checked ~ label {
color: #ffc700;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
color: #deb217;
}

.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
color: #c59b08;
}'''
```

Comment: Fix the mismatch between the radio buttons IDs, and the label's `for` attributes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.